# how to call all items in a list at once?

Tags: python, list, pygame

```
for i in objects:
    if self.y + self.y_vel > HEIGHT+self.ySize:
        self.y_vel = 0
        break
    elif pygame.Rect.colliderect(self.rect, i.rect):
        self.y_vel = 0
        break
    else:
        self.y_vel += 0.05
```

this code works all right till the last else because the for loop maybe hasn't reached the object its colliding with so it gives it gravity so my question is is there a way to do `pygame.Rect.colliderect(self.rect, all(i).rect)` but that doesn't work I experimented with all() but I don't really know how that would work any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) but [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). Also, you need to restructure the code, because when the object collides with the ground, you don't need to check for collisions with objects:

```py
if self.y + self.y_vel > HEIGHT+self.ySize:
    self.y_vel = 0
else:
    if any(self.rect.colliderect(o.rect) for o in objects):
        self.y_vel = 0
    else:
        self.y_vel += 0.05
```

However, you don't want to let the object float slightly over the obstacle. So you might want to place the object tight to the obstacle when you detect a collision:

```py
self.rect.y = self.y + self.y_vel

if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
    self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
    self.y = self.rect.y
    self.y_vel = 0

else:
    collided = False
    for o in objects:
        if self.rect.colliderect(o.rect):
            collided = True
            self.rect.bottom = o.rect.top
            self.y = self.rect.y
            self.y_vel = 0
            break

    if not collided:
        self.y_vel += 0.05
```